# How can differentiate between clients on socket.io or send a message to an specific client/user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm programing a real time application using websockets, but when i emit the messages from a server (node.js):

```
//Mostramos el 'dashboard' de dispositivo
const getSingleDevice = async (req, res) => {

    /*Realizamos una busqueda dentro de la base de datos*/
    const device = await Device.findById(req.params.id);

    console.log('device: ', device)

    //Importamos la conexion del servidor de Sockets
    const connectionSocket = require('../../lib/socketManager').connection();

    //Importamos la conexion del servidor mqtt
    const connectionMqtt = require('../../lib/mqttManager').connection();

    //Creamos una funcion que se ejecutara cada vez que recibimos un dato por mqtt
    //En este caso enviamos por websockets
    let sendToSocket = async (d) => {

        //Conversion de los datos
        let data = JSON.parse(d.replace(/'/g, "\""));

        connectionSocket.sendEvent('temperature', data.temperature);
        connectionSocket.sendEvent('humidity', data.humidity);

        //console.log('Enviando al Socket: ',data.token);  
        //console.log('Enviando al Socket: ',data.temperature);  
        //console.log('Enviando al Socket: ',data.humidity); 

        //Verificamos el 'token'
        //Notese que dentro de 'decoded' se encuentra el 'id' del 'user'
        //al que le corresponde dicho 'id'

        await jwt.verify(data.token, config.secret, (error, decoded) => {

            //Si NO existe el 'user' devolvemos un estado de error
            if (error) {
                console.log('Token No valido')
                //return res.status(404).send('El TOKEN ES INCORRRECTO o hay un error de servidor');
            } else {

                //Mostramos en consola
                //console.log('token: ', data.token);
                //console.log('topic', topic);
                //console.log('decoded: ', decoded);

                if (decoded.id === device.userOwnerId) {

                    console.log('Identificador: ', device.userOwnerId + '/' + device._id);

                    //Enviamos por el socket
                    connectionSocket.sendEvent('temperature', data.temperature);
                    connectionSocket.sendEvent('humidity', data.humidity);
                    connectionSocket.sendEvent('id', device.userOwnerId + '/' + device._id);

                } else {

                    console.log('Identificador no valido: ', device.userOwnerId + '/' + device._id);

                }

            };

        });

    };

    //Armamos el topic
    topic = device.userOwnerId + '/' + device._id;
    console.log('topic: ', topic);

    //Registramos un dato recibido por mqtt y lo enviamos al 'socket'
    connectionMqtt.registerMQTT(topic, sendToSocket);

    //Renderizamos
    res.render('devices/detail-device', {
        device
    });
}
```

To a client (HTML/javascript), i'm using handlebars from node.js in order to serve the content dinamically, i don't know if i can pass parmeters dinamically to the template in order to assemble the events:

```
//Defeinimos la direccion del servidor
//VERIFICAR PRIMERO
const host = 'http://192.168.1.106:3000';

//Almacenamos el dato proveniente del servidor
let sensorStatus = 0;

//Creamos una conexion socket con el servidor
//VERIFICAR la direccion EL SERVIDOR DEL API DE DESTINO Primero
const connection = io(host);

//Ejecutamos tan pronto se cargue la ventana
window.onload = function() {

    //connection.emit('Prueba', 'Hello server from client');

    //Escichamos el evento 'connect' para verificar la conexion con el servidor
    //Mostramos en consola si todo ha salido bien
    connection.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('Enlazado con el servidor: ', host);
    });

    //Recibimos del servidor del valor por medio de websockets
    connection.on('temperature', function(data) {

        console.log('temperature: ', data);

        //Cambiamos el valor de la grafica
        updateGauge(data);

    });

    `//Recibimos del servidor del valor por medio de websockets`


    connection.on('humidity', function(data) {



        console.log('humidity: ', data);
    });

    //Recibimos del servidor del valor por medio de websockets
    connection.on('id', function(data) {

        console.log('id: ', data);
    });
};
```

BUT the data is received by ALL clients, no matter if the client is logged or not, i'm using jwt and user and devices id in order to authenticate. How can i differentiate between clients and make the message to arrive to the desired/SPECIFIC logged client?

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you trying to send to one specific user?

Comment: Also, are you using plain webSocket or socket.io?  You seem to refer to both, but they are not the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm using socket.io and thse are the specific lines ('im using a customized class for do it): //Enviamos por el socket
            connectionSocket.sendEvent('temperature', data.temperature);
            connectionSocket.sendEvent('humidity', data.humidity);
            connectionSocket.sendEvent('id', device.userOwnerId+'/'+device._id);

Comment: What socket.io library are you using?  I'm not familiar with `connectionSocket.sendEvent()` or with this `const connectionSocket = require('../../lib/socketManager').connection();`.

Comment: Also, what client are you trying to send the message to?  Is it the one that initiated the `getSingleDevice()` request?

Comment: I'm using a separated class in order to send the events is to long to post here but basically the function is:         //En caso de existir un Socket utilizables
      this._socket.emit(event, data);

Comment: With "const connectionSocket = require('../../lib/socketManager').connection(); " i just only importing the io objects, in order to re use in the project, i  call "getSingleDevice()" the route here: //Metodo 'GET' para ver el dispositivo en detalle 'id'
router.get('/devices/:id', isLoggedIn, getSingleDevice);

Comment: I still don't know which client you're trying to send to?

Comment: Sorry for the english and thank you for the answer: The client is the srcript of javascript(second part) that is served on the web browser. I don't know what you mean

Comment: The server has many clients connected.  When you want to send data with `sendEvent()` which client do you want to sent that data to?  That's the crux of the problem here.  All the clients presumably have the same script tag served to them so that's not the answer.  Do you want the `sendEvent()` to go to the same client that sent the request that triggered `getSingleDevice()`?  And, is that request from an Ajax call or from a browser web page request (in the browser URL bar)?